# Consolidate multiple Ethereum accounts

Tags: ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, smart-contract-wallets, erc

I have multiple Ethereum accounts with pretty small amount of Ether, like equivalent of $20…$50
Is it possible to consolidate all wallets and/or transfer the all coins to a single wallet in Ethereum or any other blockchain?
Can you suggest if any smart contract is capable of that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to consolidate your Ethereum wallets by transferring the Ether from each wallet to a single one.

To do this, you simply initiate a transfer from each of the smaller wallets to the address of the destination wallet.

There's no need for a smart contract for this; regular transactions will do the job.

Keep in mind, though, that each transaction will require gas fees, which are paid in Ether and vary based on network congestion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The way you described is obvious, and will result gas charges for the each small transactions. Is it possible to avoid it? Is it possible having the smart contract to transfer the funds from >10 Ethereum wallets to one (may be any blockchain) and get gas charges for  one “big” transaction less than sum of each “small” transaction?

Comment: @Xytrax Sorry, but that is not possible.